I have to upload my research article on arXiv but I am not affiliated with any institute
I have to upload a pure theoretical physics research article on arXiv but I don't have endorsement of affiliation. What do I do?

Can you find someone to sponsor you?

@Buffy no, I can't

Then you can't upload to arxiv. Have you tried to find someone? Do you have any academic contacts from your past? If not, the probability is low that you have a useful contribution to make and that's why you're not allowed to submit.

@BryanKrause how do you know for sure that if someone can make a useful contribution or not?

@Anyon that should help. Thanks.

I don't know for sure, I said low probability. The reason is that science is built on the contributions of what came before, and because it's really really hard to do new research, so it typically requires extensive training. Just like you wouldn't expect someone who never did it before without training to build a house.
